# How to append a column to a file using savetxt

Tags: python, append

I am trying to save an array as a column into a file every time it is updated as follow:

```
f = open('test.txt','a')

for j in range(1,10):

    np.savetxt(f,u0)
    for k in range(1,m):
        u[k] = u0[k] - 0.25*beta*(u0[k+1]**2 - u0[k-1]**2)
        u0[k-1] = tmp[k-1]
        tmp[k] = u[k]
```

Here u0, u, and tmp are arrays of the same size. At the moment savetxt just append u[0] into one column. Is there a way to add u0 (after it is updated) to the file as a new column every time?

Comment: You want to make a new column at each iteration, am I understanding things correctly?

Comment: @AMC that is correct.

Comment: You could write each array to a file, and then parse and combine the files. How many arrays are there, and why do you need to do this?

Comment: In the end, there will be 75 arrays. I am solving a PDE. I was told that I need to save the solutions at each time step. Normally, I would have made a 2D array, but the instructions seem to implied that I can only two two 1D arrays (one for a previous time step and one for the solutions at the next time step).